# Trying to line up text under Font Awesome icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm currently using 2 Font Awesome icons. The problem is that I want to add text under each one that align with these icons. The problem is that the text is centered on the page but not under the corresponding icons.

Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <h1 class="brand-heading">Title</h1>
            <p class="intro-text">description</p>
            <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll btn-lg">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#contact" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-up animated"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>About   Contact
</div>
```

Comment: May help to use `fa-fw` clad so your icons confirm to one size as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do.  Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/plushyObject/02s7wnm8/

```
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center outline">
                <h1 class="brand-heading">Title</h1>
                <p class="intro-text">description</p>
                <div class="col-sm-4 outline">
                    <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll btn-lg outline">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-fw"></i>
                    </a>
                    <p class="outline">
                        Text is centered by 'text-center' class inherited from first 
                        column.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you text-align the parent element, it will be inherited by the picture.

```
CSS

.container {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Line it up using an HTML `<table>`, and style it with CSS.  That way it will stay on top of the icons correctly.

### http://jsfiddle.net/vd6smL75/

Comment: Perfect. That worked very good. I ended up doing it a little different but that got me started on the right direction.

Comment: The downvotes would be because of the use of a table for formatting, which is an almost-universally frowned upon method of laying out a webpage in today's web. There is (almost? I don't know of any counter-examples) always a more semantically correct method to achieve the same result.